# Using Googlemaps API to guide a user to a location (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to guide a user from one point on a map to another. I can add the locations I want to the overlay.

I want the user to be able to pick a location and be guided through the streets to that location.

Does anyone know how to do this, or is it even available in the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android 2.2, there are no published `Intents` to launch directly into Google Navigation, let alone specify start and end points. Hopefully, they will add this someday. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying, It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it were available it would be in the directions part of the api. In the standard API it looks like directions are supported.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsService

Is this the API you have access to? If so you are set to go.

Comment: I only have access to the android google-apis. Your answer is much appreciated though

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to fire up Google Maps to get directions from pre-determined start and destination coordinates:

Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com//mapssaddr=4.16334,101.5449&daddr=5.4422,100.31");
Intent mViewChaptersIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);       startActivity(mViewChaptersIntent);

Is this what you had in mind?